# Google Apps Calendar free/busy query POST with curl

Tags: php, post, curl, google-calendar-api, google-apps-for-education

I am trying to do a free/busy query on a Google Resource Calendar (Google Apps). The API documentation for Freebusy query gives these directions about the request:

HTTP Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy
```

Request Body Structure:

```
{  "timeMin": {datetime},
   "timeMax": {datetime},
   "items": [
      {"id": {string}
      }
    ]
}
```

Here's my attempt, using curl:

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy";
global $headers;  // holds ClientLogin authentification

$freebusy_post = array(

        "timeMin" => '2012-12-31T00:00:00',
        "timeMax" => '2013-01-08T23:00:00',
        "timeZone" => 'America/New York',

/*** "items" below commented out because posting a multidimensional array returns an 
"Array to string conversion" error. However, I think the API requires 
"items" to be an array. ***/

        //"items" => array(
        //        "id" => "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/gdev.wellesley.edu_313736333535343332@resource.calendar.google.com" 
        //        )

/*** My attempt at using a plain string instead of an array ***/

        "items" => "gdev.wellesley.edu_313736333535343332@resource.calendar.google.com",        

); 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $freebusy_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($data);
```

My problem: $data doesn't print anything.

I'm brand new to PHP, curl, and the Google Apps Calendar API. I'd love any help/ lessons/ advice you can offer!

Comment: if `var_dump($data)` shows it's a boolean false, then something failed with curl, and you need to check `curl_error()` for why.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you have probably to convert the php array to a json first.

```
$freebusyjson = json_encode($freebusy_post);
```

Answer (score 0):

i started with your code and modified it and the following worked for me...

Note how i formatted the calendar ID in the item variable. I also only needed to attach an API key to the URL as it is a public calendar. I don't think I needed it initially, but then I reached the number of requests that could be made without using an API key.

Finally, note the format of the Time/Date. I'm saying this is the only way to do it, but it worked for me.

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy/?key=MY_API_KEY";

$freebusy_post = array(
        "timeMin" => '2016-11-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        "timeMax" => '2016-12-21T00:00:00.000Z',
        "timeZone" => ' America/New York',
        "items" => array(array('id'=>"mywebsite.com_randomlettershere@group.calendar.google.com")),        

);

$freebusy_post = json_encode($freebusy_post);
$ch = curl_init();curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $freebusy_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($data);
```